# How to validate a CheckBox with CustomValidator within a RadListView

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a `Telerik:RadListView` control and multiple checkboxes in it. I need to validate those checkboxes before submitting the form. 
I have tried build-in validators with `ControlToValidate` property but it gave me the error `Control 'chkQuestion' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'chkQuestionValidator' cannot be validated.` which is very logical because they are all in a `RadListView`.

After that, i created a CustomValidator;

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkQuestion" 
CssClass="AcceptedAgreement"
 Visible="true" 
runat="server" 
Text=" I confirm" 
AutoPostBack="false" />

<asp:CustomValidator 
ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate" 
EnableClientScript="true" 
ID="chkQuestionValidator" 
runat="server" 
Enabled="true" 
SetFocusOnError="true" 
ErrorMessage="Please confirm" 
ForeColor="Red" />
```

these are all in `Telerik:RadListView` which means i have multiple of them but i cant link them in my client-side custom validator function.

Here is my validator function:

```
   function CheckBoxRequired_ClientValidate(sender, e) {
           var c = jQuery(".AcceptedAgreement input:checkbox");
           var chb = validator

           if (c.is(':checked')) {
               e.IsValid = true;
           } else {
               e.IsValid = false;
           }
       }
```

but with this function i cant validate them seperately. when one of the checkboxes checked, this function act like all of them are checked. this is because they all have same css class, and this is the point i stucked.

if you help me, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**For those who come here for solution, here it is:**

```
        function handleSubmitForm(sender, args) {
            var c = jQuery(".AcceptedAgreement input:checkbox");
            c.each(function (index) {
                if (!c[index].checked) {
                    args.set_cancel(true);
                }
            });
            args.set_cancel(true);
        }
```

basically i assign this piece of code to my button, it is called before doing postback, and if it does not fit my condition, it stops the postback. you can do whatever you want in if clause.

you can call this function :

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="btnSubmit" 
OnClientClicking="handleSubmitForm"
Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```